# Left/Right float button inside div

Tags: css, html

How can I make button float only in div area?

Here is my example CSS and HTML.

```css
.test {
  width: 60%;
  display: inline;
  overflow: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin: 0px auto;
}
```

```html
<div class='test'>
  <div style='float: left;'>
    <button>test</button>
  </div>
  <div style='float: right;'>
    <button>test</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want it to be like this.

[image]

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Change display:inline to display:inline-block

```
.test {
  width:200px;
  display:inline-block;
  overflow: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin:0px auto;
  border:1px red solid;
}
```

Answer (score 18):

You can use [`justify-content: space-between`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content) in `.test` like so:

```css
.test {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 20rem;
  border: .1rem red solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  <button>test</button>
  <button>test</button>
</div>
```

---

For those who want to use Bootstrap 4 can use [`justify-content-between`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/utilities/flex/#justify-content):

```css
div {
  width: 20rem;
  border: .1rem red solid;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
  <button>test</button>
  <button>test</button>
</div>
```