# How to put a button on the right side of a div

Tags: html, css

It may appear an obvious question, but check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vbu23uom/2/) which contains the following code

```
<div style="border:1px #aaa solid;" id="srd_header">
    <button style=" float:right" onClick="window.external.Test();">Close</button>
</div>
```

As you see, the button doesn't position inside the `div` and the division doesn't surround the button! I used `float:right` for the button to push it to the right side.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18006694/left-right-float-button-inside-div

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to apply a [**clearfix**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/211383/3597276) solution to the parent `div`, since you are floating the child (`button`).

One clearfix method is `overflow: auto`.

```
<div style="border:1px #aaa solid; background-color:red; overflow: auto;" id="srd_header">
    <button style=" float:right" onClick="window.external.Test();">Close</button>
</div>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/vbu23uom/3/)

Another, simpler and more modern, approach would be to avoid floats and use [**flexbox**](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

```
<div style="border:1px #aaa solid; background-color:red; 
                display: flex; justify-content: flex-end;" id="srd_header">
    <button onClick="window.external.Test();">Close</button>
</div>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/vbu23uom/4/)

Answer (score 1):

That's because of the `float` on your button.

EDIT: If you want the button to stay on the right-hand side, use `text-align:right;` on the `<div>`.

EDIT2: Here's your fiddle updated to see it all together. Just a minor change in the CSS and everything works fine :-)  http://jsfiddle.net/vbu23uom/5/

Comment: Then how to push the button to the right side without float?

Comment: Thanks, yes, it works! however to push just the button on the right side and not the text (that may come later), I think the other answer is more fitted to my needs, thank you for help.